# What are preferred cryptographic hashing functions in Python (preferably provided in hashlib)?

Tags: python, cryptography, hash, hashlib

I thought this would be covered by https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html or by a question on StackOverflow, but I didn't find it covered.

What are reasonably cryptographically strong ways to create a hash code for X many bytes in Python, preferably available in hashlib? The docs mention known collision weaknesses, but don't say which are now cracked and which have no publicly known exploits.

I'm not specifically looking only for the strongest cryptography I can reasonably acquire, but which hashlib options come with hashlib that are preferred among the readily available options.

Comment: You should take a look at https://cryptography.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

Your link states that MD5, SHA1 and multiple variants of SHA2
(SHA224, 256, 384, 512) are guaranteed to be supported.
(it also says to look in the See-also-section for weaknesses...)

Of of those, the current state:
MD5 is *bad*.
SHA1: avoid it if possible.
SHA2: OK, but don´t choose 224 (or, better, use only 512)

(This is not a Phyton problem).

Comment: @Editor: Don´t remove line breaks as "typo fix" (Reviewers: It´s pretty much clear that you didn´t check the edit). And SHA1 is better than MD5, but "decent"? Google before you say that...